# C# WPF DataGrid crashes app when changing cell value thats binded to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm new to this databinding stuff. but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I have a simple form with a datagrid on it. I create an observablecollection of a class. the class is just two properties. I bind to the observablecollection and the datagrid shows has the data shown. so that's working but if I go to change change a value in the datagrid by double clicking on the cell. when I hit enter it crashes.

here is code

```
namespace TESTDELETE
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Basemap> BMList;
        {
            BMList = new ObservableCollection<Basemap>();
            BMList.Add(new Basemap("filename1", "desc1"));
            BMList.Add(new Basemap("filename2", "desc2"));
            BMList.Add(new Basemap("filename3", "desc3"));   
        }
        datagrid1.DataContext = BMList;

    }
}
}
```

here is my class

```
 namespace TESTDELETE
 public class Basemap
{
    private string bmfilename;
    private string bmdesc;
    public Basemap(string filename, string desc)
    {
        this.bmfilename = filename;
        this.bmdesc = desc;
    }
    public string BMFileName {
        get {
            return bmfilename;
        }
        set { 
            BMFileName = value;
        }
    }
    public string BMDesc
    {
        get
        {
            return bmdesc;
        }
        set
        {
            BMDesc = value;
        }
    }

}
}
```

and here is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TESTDELETE.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Initialized="Window_Initialized">
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="339,175,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <TabControl Margin="10">
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

the error happens in basemap class. when trying to change the value of a cell in the datagrid the error happens in the set function of the property that's changed. 
for example after the form loads I change the cell that contains the value desc3. the error would happen in the set function of the BMDesc in the Basemap class.
the error says an unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in the TESTDELETE.exe

Any help would be awesome.

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BMFileName` and `BMDesc` property setters should not set their own value because it will generate an infinite loop which crashes your application. You should valorize private members instead:

```
public class Basemap
{
    private string bmfilename;
    private string bmdesc;

    public Basemap(string filename, string desc)
    {
        this.bmfilename = filename;
        this.bmdesc = desc;
    }

    public string BMFileName
    {
        get
        {
            return bmfilename;
        }
        set
        {
            bmfilename = value;
        }
    }
    public string BMDesc
    {
        get
        {
            return bmdesc;
        }
        set
        {
            bmdesc = value;
        }
    }
}
```